# Running Graylog in a Kubernetes cluster behind an ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, graylog

I'm trying to set up Graylog within my Kubernetes cluster as described [here](https://github.com/mouaadaassou/K8s-Graylog). The problem I'm running into is the definition of the environment variable GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI. The documentation tells me to enter "my IP adress" and from what I was able to find out, the variable is ment to tell the browser where to find the Graylog API.

But my cluster is accessed through a NGINX reverse proxy serving as an ingress controller, which means the browser can't access the Graylog pod directly and even less through http, so it don't really know what value I should assing there. I tried the public IP address of the ingress controller but all I'm getting is a 503. **Is there a way to allow access to the Graylog API while still keeping the service protected behind the ingress controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how are you exposing it. By default it's not exposed to the outside world. We have `graylog3` service of type `NodePort`, so we have only an internal IP that can be accessed from another pod or used to expose it with ingress.

```
$ kubectl get service -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE   SELECTOR
es6          NodePort    10.23.244.28    <none>        9200:30001/TCP,9300:30002/TCP    54m   service=es-deploy
graylog3     NodePort    10.23.242.128   <none>        9000:30003/TCP,12201:30004/TCP   54m   service=graylog-deploy
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.23.240.1     <none>        443/TCP                          57m   <none>
mongo        ClusterIP   10.23.243.160   <none>        27017/TCP                        54m   service=mongo-deploy
```

If we curl this service and port from another pod we have the following output:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti ubuntu -- curl 10.23.242.128:9000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Graylog Web Interface</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/favicon.png">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/config.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/vendor.4024e2a8db732781a971.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/polyfill.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/builtins.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/plugin/org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.ThreatIntelPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.ThreatIntelPlugin.b864ba54b438ac0bdc48.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/plugin/org.graylog.plugins.collector.CollectorPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.plugins.collector.CollectorPlugin.bcc87290018e859a8a9e.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/plugin/org.graylog.aws.AWSPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.aws.AWSPlugin.8ae7cb13983ce33eeb5b.js"></script>

    <script src="http://your_ip_address:30003/assets/app.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

As can be seen, there is a reference for `http://your_ip_address:30003`. If we leave it this way, the application will break because it's referencing something nonexistent.

So I'll change 2 things, make it visible from the outside world with an ingress and change `GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI` to the correct IP I'll get:

1 - Creating ingress rule to expose Graylog:

This is how my ingress manifest is looking

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: graylog
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: graylog3
    servicePort: 9000
```

```
$ kubectl get ingresses 
NAME      HOSTS   ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
graylog   *       34.107.139.231   80      56s
```

2 - Edit our `GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI` and substitute `http://your_ip_address:30003` for `http://34.107.139.231:80`.

Observe that here I'm changing port from `30003` to `80` since our ingress rule is exposing on port `80`.

```
$ kubectl edit deployments graylog-deploy
```

Changes made, now let's curl this port from any console (give it some time for the pods to be recreated):

```
$ curl 34.107.139.231:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Graylog Web Interface</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/favicon.png">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/config.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/vendor.4024e2a8db732781a971.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/polyfill.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/builtins.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/plugin/org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.ThreatIntelPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.ThreatIntelPlugin.b864ba54b438ac0bdc48.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/plugin/org.graylog.plugins.collector.CollectorPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.plugins.collector.CollectorPlugin.bcc87290018e859a8a9e.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/plugin/org.graylog.aws.AWSPlugin/plugin.org.graylog.aws.AWSPlugin.8ae7cb13983ce33eeb5b.js"></script>

    <script src="http://34.107.139.231:80/assets/app.a5e2fb591e8fd54ee4ef.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now we can see `http://34.107.139.231:80/` as expected and the page can be loaded perfectly.

If you have a domain name that's redirecting to your application IP, put it in this variable.

Comment: But isn't this undermining the purpose of having an ingress controller, which is to prevent direct access to your resources, posing a security issue?

Comment: My example is trying to show you how to understand which IP should be used in `GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI`. You are right, using ingress is a much better approach but for my example I choose to expose it using `LoadBalancer` just to make things faster and more didactic. In the end, doesn't matter how are you exposing it, `GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI` should be the external ip/name used to access  Graylog dashboard.

Comment: I just realised that I might not have formulated my question clearly: Accessing the API while still keeping the service protected behind the ingress is the actual point of what I'm trying to do here, so exposing the entire thing as a load balancer is unfortunately not an option for me.

Comment: I edited my answer changing the approach. Now we are exposing it using `ingress` instead of `LoadBalancer`. Please check it and let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Strange, that's basically the same thing I'm doing. I'll look more into this tomorrow, maybe I'll find a mistake I made. Anyway, thanks for your help. :D

Comment: If you need more help, please let me know. Posting your custom manifest and I can try to reproduce here.

Comment: Alright that problem seems to be solved, I discovered some copy-paste errors in the elasticsearch yaml and I also used port 30003 with the ingress instead of 9000. Now I still need to teach it to use https but that's a different story. Thanks again for your time.